# Android 4.3 on Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, x86, kernel, qemu

How to run `x86` or `arm` image built by myself in Android emulator for **Windows**.
For Linux it works fine.

I've built image from latest `AOSP` sources.

When I tried to launch it in emulator i've got following errors with `--show-kernel` option.

> [    0.470232] SELinux: Loaded policy from /sepolicy
>   [    0.470232] init (1): /proc/1/oom_adj is deprecated, please use /proc/1/oom_score_adj instead.
>   [    0.523298] init: cannot open '/initlogo.rle'
>   [    0.530295] goldfish_nand_read: invalid read, start 0, len 200, dev_size 21560000, write_size 800
>   [    0.530295] end_request: I/O error, dev mtdblock0, sector 2
>   [    0.543558] EXT4-fs (mtdblock0): unable to read superblock
>   [    0.550943] fs_mgr: Cannot mount filesystem on /dev/block/mtdblock0 at /system

As I know since 4.3 android use `ext-4`

So i decide to rebuild `kernel-qemu` by [this instruction](http://source.android.com/source/building-kernels.html)

It's not helped too.

How can I launch `x86` or `arm` Android 4.3 image on Emulator for **Windows**?

**EDIT**:
Solution for x86 [**was found here**](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-atom-x86-image-for-android-jelly-bean-43-installation-instructions-manually)
But  it works only for downloaded image!
How can I run newly built 4.3 image from Android Sources?
Newly built image works fine on Linux, on windows I see only black screen, but already without error above.

Comment: Have you taken a look at GenyMotion? I think they added some kind of a beta version to support Android 4.3 http://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: @MagicMicky Thanks for interesting link, but i need to run original image image on original Emulator.

Comment: Does the same happen if you build a 4.2 image, or is this limited strictly to 4.3?

Comment: @Geobits It's only for 4.3

Answer (score 3):

People experiencing a black screen should try updating their Intel HAXM driver. Fixed it for me!

Comment: After updating with the SDK Manager, did you run the installer android-sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\InteHaxm.exe ?

Comment: This fixed it for me! I had Intel HAXM 1.0.1 installed. Had to uninstall it and install the latest 1.0.6 version.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse out this AOSP update as I don't think they have finished the patch set yet (as using Ext4 on the images with buffers this size causes the problem).

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/85a347d34db27aa0fff6b67131864921dfa3941c%5E1..85a347d34db27aa0fff6b67131864921dfa3941c/

Comment: Thanks for idea, but image not working since they moved to 4.3

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem since 4.2 and I fixed it today by doing the following:

a) for Android 4.4, go here and follow the instructions:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-atom-x86-image-for-android-4-4-kitkat-installation-instructions-manually

4.04, 4.1.1, 4.2 and 4.3 can be found on their Tools and Downloads page.

b) update the Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (1.0.6 at time of writing) from here:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager/

When creating the emulator, I used the values given on the instruction page and the emulator started on my first try, even though it took longer than usual.

I hope this helps someone.

Good luck!